# Deleting, adding and updating Firestore documents when offline

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using the following code in my iOS Swift app:

```
class ProfileController
{
    func remove(pid: String, completion: @escaping ErrorCompletionHandler)
    {
        guard let uid = self.uid else
        {
            completion(Errors.userIdentifierEmpty)
            return
        }

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userDocument = db.collection("profiles").document(uid)
        let collection = userDocument.collection("profiles")
        let document = collection.document(pid)

        document.delete()
        {
            error in

            completion(error)
        }
    }
}
```

When the device is online, everything works fine. The completion handler of the `delete`call is properly executed. However, when I am offline, I have noticed that the completion handler will not be executed as long as I am offline. As soon as I get back online, the completion handler will be called almost immediately.
I don't want to wait until the user is back online (which could take forever), so I changed the code a little bit and added a `ListenerRegistration`:

```
class ProfileController
{
    func remove(pid: String, completion: @escaping ErrorCompletionHandler)
    {
        guard let uid = self.uid else
        {
            completion(Errors.userIdentifierEmpty)
            return
        }

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userDocument = db.collection("profiles").document(uid)
        let collection = userDocument.collection("profiles")
        let document = collection.document(pid)

        var listener: ListenerRegistration?

        listener = document.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: false)
        {
            snapshot, error in

            listener?.remove() // Immediately remove the snapshot listener so we only receive one notification.

            completion(error)

            listener = nil
        }

        document.delete()
    }
}
```

Although this works fine, I am not sure if this is the right way to go. I have read online that a snapshot listener can be used in real-time scenarios, which is not really what I am looking for (or what I need).
Is this the right approach or is there another (better) way? I only want to get notified once (thus I added the includeMetadataChanged property and set it to false). I also remove the `ListenerRegistration` once the completion handler was called once.

If the first approach does not work properly when being offline - what are the use cases of this approach? Before I change my entire codebase to use listeners, is there any way of executing the completion handler of the first approach when the device is offline?

**TL;DR**: The second implementation works fine, I am simply unsure if this is the proper way of receiving notifications when the device is offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the first approach does not work properly when being offline - what are the use cases of this approach?

It depends on what you mean by "work properly".  The behavior you're observing is **exactly** as intended.  Write operations are not "complete" until they're registered at the server.

However, all writes (that are not transactions) are actually committed locally before they hit the server.  These local changes will **eventually** be synchronized with the server at some point in the future, even if the app is killed and restarted.  The change is not lost.  You can count on the synchronization of the change to eventually hit the server as long as the user continues to launch the app - this is all you can expect.  You can read more about offline persistence in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline).

If you need to know if a prior change was synchronized, there is no easy way to determine that if the app was killed and restarted.  You could try to query for that data, if you know the IDs of the documents written, and you could check the metadata of the documents to find out the source of the data (cache or server).  But in the end, you are really supposed to trust that changes will be synchronized with the server at the earliest convenience.

If your use case requires more granularity of information, please [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When saying "does not work properly when being offline" I really meant "not working as I expected". So if I get this right, the first completion handler gets called once the data is synchronized with the server and the second handler is called whenever there are changes (no matter if local or server)?

Comment: That's correct.  Listeners get triggered when data changes from any source (including purely local).  The metadata attached to the change will tell you its source.

Comment: Listeners all the way then (at least for my scenario). Thank you.